Quick Links Web Part opens external links in a new tab regardless checkbox in link setting
Microsoft recently introduced new setting for Quick Links web part - Open link in a new tab. It works perfectly for internal links but for external links it always opens in a new tab regardlsess whether checkbox is checked or not.
Is it expected behavior? Cause from my understanding this checkbox should work the same for external and internal links.
I have created new developer tenant and new SharePoint site to test it from the scratch. And behavior is how I described.

This is expected behavior, and my test results are the same as yours.
This is to follow usability guidelines that recommend limiting the number of new windows that are automatically opened for site viewers. When a viewer wants to open a link in a new window, the guidelines recommend that the viewer be allowed to choose this outcome by "right clicking" the link.
For your reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/information-architecture-principles#think-about-link-target-interactions
